# При нажатии на кнопку SPACE скролит к якорям(JS, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код :

```
>    $(window).keypress(function(e) {
>             if (e.keyCode == 0 || e.keyCode == 32) 
>             $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:  $('.anchor').offset().top}, 350);
>     });
```

Здесь скролит при нажатии на space только до 1-го якоря(.anchor) и зависает, а мне нужно что-бы и до следующих елементов скролило при нажатии на space.
Что нужно дописать?
Буду очень благодарен за максимально быстрый ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте так:

```
var i = 0;

$(window).on("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 0 || e.keyCode == 32) {
    var $a = $('.anchor');
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $a.eq( i ).offset().top}, 350);
    i = ( i === $a.length - 1 ) ? ( 0 ) : ( i + 1 );
    // Если дойдет до последнего - вернется до первого... иначе - увеличится на 1.
  }
});
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Есть один баг, если много и быстро нажать пробел(space) сайт скроллится столько раз сколько нажмешь проблел. То есть ты уже не нажимаешь пробле, а скролл работает дальше. Как это пофиксить? Нужно как у https://aic.ru/